# I need to format text with a token

Tags: tokens

I am using tokens to display a field and want it formatted with plain text: [node:body:format-plain_text]

I have a feeling my syntax is wrong, how do I make it right?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, the answer to your question is "You cannot make it right".
This will not work like that. You are probably using entity_token as well as token. But this syntax is not supported. You will need to find a workaround for that.

Cheers and good luck!

Comment: Drupal gives me this for an option -  [node:body:?] The main body text of the node. The following properties may be appended to the token: value (Text), summary (Summary), format (Text format). That is where I got this idea from.

Comment: Right, so, the body field has the following properties attached to it: value, format, summary. The format property should return as a value the type of text format that is used on the body field, e.g. full_html, filtered_html, plain_text. The semantics of this token is not to force formatting in a specific format, but rather, to inform about the used text format.